# Delete row in AngularJS + NodeJS + Postgresql

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, postgresql, delete-row

why I can delete row in frontend but its not deleted in postgresql ?
I've been copy-paste the code from other menu in my program but it not work.
I've been try to search in google because I think my code is wrong but its SAME !

here is my ***angularJS controller***

```
 $scope.getDataLoct = function(){
    PanelEditor.getDataLoct().then(function(result) {
        console.log('result loct',result);
        var res = result.data;
        console.log('resultdataloct', res);
            $scope.tampil= res; 
    }); 
}


   $scope.deleteVenues = function(dataD, idx){
    var dataD = $scope.tampil[idx];
    console.log('dataD',dataD);
    PanelEditor.deleteVenue(dataD).then(function(result){
        console.log('sukses');
        $scope.tampil.splice(idx, 1);       
    });
}
```

here is my **angularJS HTML**

```
   <div ng-model ="info"> 
      <table  class="ui celled padded table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>No</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Addres</th>
              <th>Latitude</th>
              <th>Longitude</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="content" ng-repeat="tmp in tampil track by $index">
            <tr>
              <td class="collapsing">
                <div class="ui ribbon label">{{$index +1}}</div>
              </td>
              <td >{{tmp.title}}</td>
              <td >{{tmp.address}}</td>
              <td >{{tmp.latitude}}</td>
              <td >{{tmp.longitude}}</td>
              <td><div class="ui small blue basic icon buttons right floated">
                  <button class="ui button" tooltips tooltip-content="Edit" tooltip-side="bottom" tooltip-speed="fast" tooltip-size="small" tooltip-hide-trigger="click mouseleave" ng-click="clickMenuVenue('loct','Edit Venue','',info)">
                    <i class="write icon"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button class="ui button" tooltips tooltip-content="delete" tooltip-side="bottom" tooltip-speed="fast" tooltip-size="small" tooltip-hide-trigger="click mouseleave" ng-click="deleteVenues($index)">
                    <i class="remove icon"></i>
                  </button>
                </div></td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

here is my **angularJS  service**

```
  getDataLoct: function() {
    return $http.get('/venue/getAll/');
  },

   deleteVenue: function(dataD) {
    console.log('service',dataD);
    return $http.post('/venue/deleteVenue/',dataD);  
  }
```

here is my **NodeJS Controller**

```
 deleteVanue: function (req, res) {
        Vanue.destroy({id:req.param('id')}).exec(function (err){
          return res.json(200);
        });
    },
    getAll: function (req, res) {
        Venue.find().sort({ id: 'asc' }).exec(function (err, found){
            return res.json(200, found);
        });
    }
```

and when I clik Remove Button the Console printed this
[dataD undifinded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4szm.png)

SOMEONE CAN HELP??!!

***if my question have mistake please help me to fix it***

Comment: do you see a request going in the console for the delete? Also, you are not posting the request param that it is looking for (`id` ?) you seem to be passing the data as `dataD` which is not the id.

Comment: hmm.. its why i ask im not understand. i ve tried to ask to my brother but he said that i should fix alone.. can you help me to tell me what should I do? :D @KashyapMukkamala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your delete function:

`$scope.deleteVenues = function(dataD, idx) {..}`

you have TWO parameters in your controller.

But in the view you only call it with one parameter:

`ng-click="deleteVenues($index)"`

There are two options:

Either you pass the whole object which is to be deleted or you pass the `$index`.

Right now your app wants to read `idx` in the controller, but you are passing only one parameter. That's the reason why you get this error.

Comment: oh i see ... thanks for give me a reason :) im understand now thaaankkkss :3 @FlorianTopf